# Gradle + Spring Boot - how can I read resources in "itest" sourceSet in a test in "test" sourceSet

Tags: gradle, source-sets

I have sourceSet `itest`, `test` and `main` at the save level.

In a test in `test` sourceSet, I want to read a text file in `itest/resources`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have found the way.

Just change sourceSet `test` configuration: modify `resources.srcDirs` to add another path to the value set.

In `build.gradle`:

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        output.resourcesDir = "build/resources/test" // copy test resources to build 
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/test/resources', 'src/itest/resources/fixtures/preAuthMock2']
        // to include example json from itest resources
    }
}
```

Note that when you specify this folder which is the direct parent dir of the file you need, when you read the file with `getResourceAsStream()`, you only need `/foo.json` as the path, instead of `/fixtures/preAuthMock2/foo.json`.